# Rotate and duplicate arc by overlapping around an angle of 360 degrees

Tags: python

I wrote a python script inside dynamo which rotate and duplicate an arc of **12m** around a circle (**angle = 360°**) with a defined overlap distance and will stop if the computed remaining distance after each rotation is less then **12m**...the script works but the last arc is missed (arc < 12m) due to a non updated angles of the last arc and I dont know how to fix that.

for example if I've a circle with a radius **r = 3.742m** and overlap distance **d= 0.80m** I should get for arcs length :

(12 + 12 + 1.91) but I'm getting  (12 + 12 + 1.60)

please check my script below

```
import sys
import clr
import math
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

clr.AddReference('RevitNodes')
import Revit
from Revit.Elements import Element

element = IN[0]
cover = IN[1]
circular_bar_type = IN[2]

geo = element.Geometry()
surfaces = geo[0].Explode()

s_area = []

for i in surfaces:
    s_area.append(i.Area)
    
S_area = ["%0.2f"%(round(i,2)) for i in s_area]
    
surf = []
surf_area = set()

for s, a in zip(surfaces, S_area):
    if a not in surf_area and S_area.count(a) == 2:
        surf.append(s)
        surf_area.add(a)
#getting circular curve        
out_cir_crv = surf[1].GetIsoline(1, 0).Explode()[0]

# cover from side face to circular rebar centerline
cir_cover = circular_bar_type.GetParameterValueByName("Diamètre de barre")/2000 + cover
# overlap length
circ_overlap_length = circular_bar_type.GetParameterValueByName("Diamètre de barre")*50/1000

out_cir_crv = out_cir_crv.Offset(-cir_cover)

#getting arc of 12m length
out_arc = Arc.ByCenterPointStartPointEndPoint(out_cir_crv.CenterPoint, out_cir_crv.StartPoint, out_cir_crv.PointAtSegmentLength(12))

# fix arc direction to counter clockwise
def isclockwise(arc):
    st_vect = Vector.ByTwoPoints(arc.CenterPoint, arc.StartPoint)
    end_vect = Vector.ByTwoPoints(arc.CenterPoint, arc.EndPoint)
    cp = st_vect.Cross(end_vect)
    return cp.Z < 0

def fix_direc_arc(arc):
    if isclockwise(arc):
        return arc.Reverse()
    else:
        return arc

out_arc = fix_direc_arc(out_arc)

#define start and end arc angles
St_out_arc_angle = out_arc.StartAngle
End_out_arc_angle = out_arc.StartAngle + out_arc.SweepAngle
out_Arc = [out_arc]

#create arc rotation
k = 0
while k < 10:
    k += 1
    circ_overlap_angle = circ_overlap_length * 360 /(2* math.pi * out_arc.Radius)
    rest_arc = Arc.ByCenterPointRadiusAngle(out_arc.CenterPoint, out_arc.Radius, End_out_arc_angle - circ_overlap_angle, St_out_arc_angle + circ_overlap_angle, Vector.ZAxis())
    if rest_arc.Length < 12:
        out_Arc.append(rest_arc)
        break
    out_arc = out_arc.Rotate(out_arc.CenterPoint, Vector.ZAxis(), End_out_arc_angle - circ_overlap_angle)
    End_out_arc_angle = out_arc.StartAngle + out_arc.SweepAngle
    out_Arc.append(out_arc)
    
OUT = out_Arc
```

My result:

[image]